# Why does PostForm Map structure parse data as the key of the map?

Tags: ajax, go

We have the following AJAX call to a golang endpoint:

```
var ajaxParams = {
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/golang_endpoint'
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    timeout: timeout,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({"test": 1, "test2": "val"}),
};
$.ajax(ajaxParams);
```

However, `req.PostForm` looks like it was parsed incorrectly:

```
req.ParseForm()
fmt.Println(req.PostForm)
```

We get: `map[{"test":1,"test2":"val"}:[]]`

Why did `ParseForm` end up getting parsed this way? How can we parse it so that `PostForm` is of value `map[test: [1] test2: [val]]`

EDIT:

This is a potential solution:

```
    var ajaxParams = {
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({"test": 1, "test2": "val"}),
        ...
    };
```

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
var m map[string]interface{}
err = json.Unmarshal(data, &m)
fmt.Println(m)
```

Comment: Set `contentType: "application/json"`. Without that, it is sending it as url-encoded data, and the JSON strings becomes the key.

Comment: This did not work. When printing `req.PostForm` we get `map[]` now. Updated the question to include this.

Comment: ParseForm will parse url-encoded data. Instead, json unmarshal the result. Alternatively, you can remove contentType, use ParseForm, but not use JSON.stringify, so data is sent as url-encoded instead of JSON

Comment: The client posts JSON.  The sever expects x-www-form-urlencoded data.  Pick a data format for the request body.  Modify client or server to use that format.